# Why is my server working locally, but not on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

This is the code for my server.

```
import os
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor


class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        #self.transport.write("""connected""")
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "client connected"

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)
        print "client disconnected"

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "data is ", data

        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.message(data)

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')


factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []

ON_HEROKU = os.environ.get('ON_HEROKU')

if ON_HEROKU:
    # get the heroku port
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 17995))  
else:
    port = 3000

print "Iphone Chat server started on port: "
print port


reactor.listenTCP(port, factory)

reactor.run()
```

The code works perfectly locally, test it out for yourself. Just create a telnet communication via local host on port 3000 and you can seamlessly send and receive data.

However once I push this code to heroku and run the server, the server runs and prints out which port it is listening to, however when I try and create a connection to the server and send data, it just doesn't seem to pickup that a client is connected or send and receive data.

Can anyone resolve the issue?

Comment: Is the port 3000 open on Heroku server?

Comment: No, Heroku assigns you a dynamic port number, so the line:
`port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 17995))`  tells the code the port Heroku assigns us. The else makes sure for local testing that it chooses port 3000

Comment: What command are you using to test the server? Are you trying to connect to port `PORT` from your client?

Comment: @Lack I'm testing the connection to the server via my app that uses websockets to connect. Every time I run the app simulator I change the port number to what is printed out on the server. However if I telnet to the website on said port, i get a connection refused error.

Comment: I've never used Heroku, so I may be wrong, but elsewhere that assigned port is only used on the server side. The webhost's frontend server accepts connections on the usual ports (e.g. 80) and reroutes them to your app.

Comment: @Lack So, what are you suggesting? What do you use to host python?

Comment: Have you tried going to that address in a web browser, without specifying a port? Heroku is probably great, you just need to understand how it works: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment (not enough rep) but I think you aren't connecting to your app correctly. Usually to connect to heroku apps you connect to `http://<appname>.herokuapp.com`. I don't think you can directly connect to your app because of how heroku's routing system works.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing